# Can I use ‘dismissible’ this way?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

*Dismissible* is defined by [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dismissible) as:

> capable of being removed or taken away or dismissed

*Dismiss* is (from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismiss)):

> to permit or cause to leave

In my context, I am trying to express that a character thinks a notion he’s had is worthy of being dismissed. He thinks the idea is absurd. Aside from just sucking it up and spelling out *‘worthy of dismissal’*, which I just don’t really like the sound of, I thought I might say, *‘justifiably dismissible’*. However, that *‘capable of being’* part of the definition has me unsure if I can use the word this way. Might it come across that I’m trying to say it *should* be capable of being dismissed or in some other way that isn’t what I’m looking for?

Also, I tried to look up a single word that matches my meaning, which is ‘ridiculous enough to be disregarded’ or ‘worthy of dismissal’ (either way), but nothing good came out of it. If anyone has one on the top of their head, I’d be happy to hear it.

And here’s how I used the phrase:

> He believed the notion was (justifiably dismissible) to begin with.

Comment: 'Inconsequential' was perhaps the best answer given.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I marked this as an SWR as an afterthought. That’s not to say that I didn’t really try to find a single word to fit my meaning to begin with, because I did, and I planned to use one if someone suggested something that was better suited or it turned out that ‘justifiably dismissible’ couldn’t be used the way I wanted to. The link to the other question is helpful, but I don’t believe the answers suit or that the question is a true duplicate of my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a word that matches what you're trying to get at is [**frivolous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frivolous):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : of little weight or importance
>   // She thinks window shopping is a *frivolous* activity.
>   **1 b** : having no sound basis (as in fact or law)
>   // a *frivolous* lawsuit

Things that are *frivolous* are often ridiculous and worthy of dismissal.

That they *should* be dismissed might be implied, but it could also be the case that they could simply be ignored. (It might depend on what sense of *dismiss* is being discussed: ignore or remove?)

In any case:

> He believed the notion was *frivolous* to begin with.